# Android Gradle sync failed (import project from github)

Tags: android, android-studio, import, android-gradle-plugin

Hi guys i download a project from github and i imported in android studio , after imported am getting error

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: assert localProps['keystore.props.file']
       |         |
       |         null
       [ndk.dir:E:\sdk\ndk-bundle, sdk.dir:E:\sdk]
       Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

Gradle File:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        def Properties localProps = new Properties()
        localProps.load(new FileInputStream(file('../local.properties')))
        def Properties keyProps = new Properties()
        assert localProps['keystore.props.file'];
        keyProps.load(new FileInputStream(file(localProps['keystore.props.file'])))
        storeFile file(keyProps["store"])
        keyAlias keyProps["alias"]
        storePassword keyProps["storePass"]
        keyPassword keyProps["pass"]
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    publicBeta.initWith(buildTypes.release)
    publicBeta {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
        versionNameSuffix " Beta " + versionProps['betaNumber']
    }

    publicDebug.initWith(buildTypes.publicBeta)
    publicDebug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), file('proguard-project.txt')
        versionNameSuffix " Debug Beta " + versionProps['betaNumber']
    }
}
```

}

I realy don't know what to do.

Does anyone have any suggestions?.

Comment: Yes you can refer this link , hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310157/gradle-android-studio-signing-with-a-properties-file

Comment: you should create `keystore.props.file`

Comment: In the gradle script there is a referece to this file which is not present in your project

Answer (score 6):

In the root folder of your project, you should have `keystore.properties` and `local.properties` files.

`keystore.properties` should have something like this:

```
store=/path/to/your.keystore
alias=your_alias
pass=your_password
storePass=your_keystore_password
```

In `local.properties`, **add the last line.**

```
ndk.dir=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle    
sdk.dir=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
# Add the line below
keystore.props.file=../keystore.properties
```

See [a commit here](https://github.com/prt2121/dashclock/commit/189f123a2353fd20ed08d6d4055dc922d177293e) or check [the modified project](https://github.com/prt2121/dashclock).

Or if you need a quick dirty fix, just make the gradle script the same as a standard one by replacing the android block with this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When I got such an error, it was because I was using JDK8, while the imported github repo was using JDK7.

Also make sure you have "Android Support Repository" installed from SDK Manager > Extras.